# Adjust attribute of html textarea dynamically?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, textarea, autocorrect

I have the following textarea:

```
<textarea id="edit-note-text" autocorrect="on"><%= text %></textarea>
```

While this text area is in use or, in other words, **while someone is typing**, I need to dynamically set the autocorrect attribute to off and back to on:

```
<textarea id="edit-note-text" autocorrect="off"><%= text %></textarea>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work:

```
document.getElementById(‘textarea’).setAttribute(‘autocorrect’, ‘off’);
```

I'm in a iOS UIWebView and could try to do this natively if possible as well but this is what comes to mind first. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        //Declare functions
            function taFocus(element){ element.setAttribute("autocorrect", "off")}
            function taBlur(element){ element.setAttribute("autocorrect", "on")}    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="edit-note-text" autocorrect="on" onfocus="taFocus(this);" onblur="taBlur(this);" >texto</textarea>
    <textarea id="edit-note-text2" autocorrect="on">texto</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some like this maybe that you need

Comment: Using 'focus' and 'blur' would definitely work but I'm trying to accomplish this on an ios device where the keyboard should definitely not be jumping up and down... unfortunately.